# lightbox wordpress gallery open popup automatics

Tags: javascript, wordpress, lightbox

I'm using the Gallery Lightbox Lite plugin in my website for gallery popup option
but I want open popup automatics after page load, do you have any javascript help me for this ?

note: this is the link to gallery
https://www.360cdm.ae/milanoorchid/en/services/kitchens/

I mean when browse this page open the gallery automatics

Best regards

Comment: the jquery `$('img').click()` function could be a solution. What did you try so far?

Comment: I want jquery help me to open the first image in gallery automatic after page load I hope you can help me to do it ? thanks

Comment: how about `$('gallery-item:first img').click()` to trigger a click on first gallery img?

Comment: thank you so much for your fast response, I tried it but it's not working I added the following code 

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('gallery-item:first img').click()
  });
</script>

Comment: its giving "TypeError: $ is not a function" - try `jQuery('gallery-item:first img').click();`

Comment: it's not working sorry ang other suggest please

Comment: might be that you need to add some delay cause the gallery ist not completely initiated

Comment: thank you , I added it in footer, it's working but without gallery popup do you know any suggest to active the popup gallery ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were using Fancybox5, it could be started on page load like this:

```js
Fancybox.fromNodes(Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[data-fancybox="gallery"]')));
```

Demo - https://jsfiddle.net/kb72pct6/